# jQuery function firing only once,

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to have 2 search box styles, one above 1000px and one below 1000px. I made that available through media queries in CSS, and then I put function on click on my element, but its only firing once, and then I need to refresh the page for it to act again. I am new to all of this, and I've searched for solutions to this problem for eight hours. I think the problem is caused by search-form--active when you click on search-trigger. But I don't know how to disable this function when browsing in under 1000px wide.

I’m working on WordPress, already created theme, called Yuuta.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.search-trigger', function() {
  $('.search-overlay').addClass('show');
  if ($('.site-header .search-form').hasClass('search-form--active')) {
    /* hide search field */
    $('.site-header .search-form').removeClass('search-form--active');
  } else {
    /* show search field */
    $('.site-header .search-form').addClass('search-form--active');
    /* focus search field */
    $('.site-header .search-field').focus();
  }
  /* show/hide search form via search icon */
  if ($('.site-header .search-trigger').hasClass('search-form--active')) {
    /* hide search field */
    $('.site-header .search-trigger').removeClass('search-form--active');
  } else {
    /* show search field */
    $('.site-header .search-trigger').addClass('search-form--active');
  }
});
```

```css
.search-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 28px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .search-trigger {
    right: 0.8em;
  }
}
.search-trigger:before {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-family: "ElegantIcons";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\55";
}
.search-trigger:before::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.search-trigger.search-form--active:before {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: .9em;
  content: "\4d";
}
.search-trigger:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
.site-header .search-form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 65px;
  bottom: 150px;
  width: 90px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.site-header .search-form input.search-field {
  width: 5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.site-header .search-form .search-submit {
  display: none;
}
.site-header .search-form.search-form--active {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  display: block;
  top: 28px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="search-trigger"></a>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Errors other other than the `Uncaught ReferenceError`, since you've not included jQuery in your demo; also `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` is [tag:php], *not* "[tag:html]."

Comment: Please provide the markup that is rendered by `<?php get_search_form(); ?>`.

Comment: @Spykee Nothing in console...
2. Sorry,its fixed and,no errors in console...
3.Sorry give me more information what is that markup,im new here :)

Comment: Have you tried to import the Jquery file before all the other javascript files on your index page? The reference error can be caused by this, which might affect your code execution.

Comment: You can try **jQuery( document ).on(...**, instead of **$( document ).on(...**. Wordpress forces some no-conflict rules.

Comment: I tried your method,i also tried http://pastebin.com/Fn8fvNpS , nothing works ... :X